# Menu block alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my menu items at the bottom to all align - products, activity feed and learn store should all be on the same line, and test should be under products, but instead what is happening is that products is pushed up, and text is aligned to the right of products.

I've tried changing the display to blocks, I've tried text-align, and nothing seems to be working.

How do you make a child menu line up with its parent items?

http://jobcreatr.com/home

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first leaf">
        <li class="leaf">
            <li class="last expanded">
                <a title="" href="http://jobcreatr.com/products">Products</a>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="first last leaf">
                        <a title="" href="http://www.google.com">test</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know CSS isn't turing complete, but it doesn't count for "programming" in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to the `<li>`'s. This works as long as they are set to `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: That worked to get them all on the same line, however the child item is still indented. Is this possibly some default styling of HTML that needs to be turned off?

Comment: In fact, it does appear to be a default styling of HTML. But you gave me the part that was really sticking me, the vertical-align part, so I'm giving you the answer.

The full answer was: vertical-align:top; on the <li> elements, and margin:0;padding:0; on the child <ul>